# Create collection containing references to items in another collection

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a table organised as columns, and I want to create a vector of rows which are hash maps whose values are mutable references to the equivalent values in the columns, so that I can then iterate over the rows, change the values which will update the values in the original columns. I think it might be to create an iterator of rows, rather than a vector of rows, but I would prefer to first learn how to do a vector (if possible) since this project is for the purpose of me learning rust. Below is what I have so far, but I am getting the error

```
cannot borrow `columns` as mutable more than once at a time
`columns` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

which I can't find a solution to. In the below I create `columns` which holds the original data, `rows` which should hold references to the data in `columns`, and then I try to update `columns` by getting `cell` from `rows` and assigning a new value to it.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Column {
    name: String,
    data: Vec<i32>,
}
fn main() {
    let mut columns = vec![
        Column {
            name: String::from("col1"),
            data: vec![4, 5, 6],
        },
        Column {
            name: String::from("col2"),
            data: vec![7, 8, 9],
        },
    ];
    println!("{:?}", columns);

    let mut rows = Vec::new();
    let columns_len = columns[0].data.len();
    for i in 0..columns_len {
        let mut row = HashMap::new();
        for column in columns.iter_mut() {
            row.insert(&column.name, column.data.get_mut(i).unwrap());
        }
        rows.push(row);
    }
    println!("{:?}", rows);
    let cell = rows
        .get_mut(1)
        .unwrap()
        .get_mut(&String::from("col2"))
        .unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", cell);
    **cell = 99;
    println!("{:?}", columns);
    println!("{:?}", rows);
    println!("{:?}", cell);
}
```

Comment: Won't solve your problem, but `column.data.get_mut(i).unwrap()` could be more simply written `&mut column.data[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many times it is useful to think of mutable references as *exclusive* references. That is, instead of thinking that they allow you to modify the value, think of them as guaranteeing that this is the only *live* reference that can use that valule, and that the mutability thing is just a nice side effect.

With that in mind, if you manage to get a `Vec` of mutable references to the individual values of your `columns`, then the `columns` themselves will be inaccesible (remember, exclusive access).

And when you create `cell` that is an exclusive reference to the `rows` vector, then this vector will be inaccessible for the lifetime of `cell`.

That said, you can create an array of mutable references to the contents of your `columns`, as long as you are careful with the iterator API (the `get_mut()` will not do because the compiler cannot assure that you do not use the same index twice):

```
    // First create the hash maps
    let mut rows = std::iter::repeat_with(|| HashMap::new())
        .take(columns[0].data.len())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    
    // Then fill in the references.
    for c in columns.iter_mut() {
        for (id, d) in c.data.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            rows[id].insert(c.name.as_str(), d);
        }
    }
```

Note that the `rows` variable has type: `Vec<HashMap<&str, &mut i32>>`, that I don't know if it will be so useful.

In practical Rust, many times it is easier to store the index of a value in the `Vec` instead of the reference to the inner value. You may think that it is not so efficient, but think of what would happen if you push into the vector and it has to reallocate its inner memory!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation it is very helpful. I need to invest much more time to properly understand borrow checking. So your example works, however I can no longer println! columns and rows after updating cell to verify they have changed, since cell now owns rows which owns columns. Is this correct?

Comment: @Max888: `cell` does not own `rows`; it borrows it exclusively (or mutably if you prefer). Once `cell` is dropped, `rows` is unborrowed and can be used again. If `cell` owned `rows` then it would instead destroy it when it is dropped.

Comment: thanks, I realised I needed to put the cell part of the code in it's own block so cell would be dropped after using it to update the value in columns, so it is all working now. thanks agains for your help!